# How to reset numastat statistics? (other than rebooting)

Tags: numa, numactl

When running the command `numastat` to see the hits, misses, foreign, etc. The counters keep increasing while running some tests.

I could make the difference between two tests to get the statistics for that test, but is there a way to reset them to 0, other than rebooting the machine?

`man` or `--help` don't provide info for this apparently.

Answer (score 2):

for your purpose (seeing the difference between the tests), you may consider using the following command:
 watch -n1 --differences=cumulative numastat

see more from here: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-numastat/